# keep google sing-in information in every activity

Tags: android, google-signin

Is it possible to store information such as email, name etc. in whole activity.

I know how to gather this information in activity wherein i initilazie sign-in button, but i dont know how to correctly keep it for next activities. I thought about store it in SQLlite, but firstly i would like to check that is it any other method.

I will be glad for any information.

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

Comment: Store it in Shared Preferences.

Comment: You need this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a BaseActivity and extend the other activities from that. Such as;

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String useremail;
    public static String username;
}


public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
    String name = username;
    String email = useremail;
}
```

Or you can create getter setters and use that.
Just make your other activities extends BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

you can use [shared prefrences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for sroring and getting data every where in your app

Comment: Thanks, i will test it